# Answer to android phone calls from PC by bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have a PC (where a Java program is running), Bluetooth dongle and Android device (2.3. 6) and want to use PC microphone/headset/speakers to answer a call by Bluetooth. I give another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818704/is-it-possible-to-send-receive-voice-from-pc-to-android-device-over-bluetooth), but seems we not understand each other. I not want to speak with PC by connected Android device, I want to answer to incoming calls by PC (use PC as Bluetooth headset or HFP headset or something like that). I find app in play.google.com that implemented such things [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=justPhone.remotePhone).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to make the computer act as a Bluetooth Handsfree Kit, in fact it's already implemented in most OS with or without additional software.

In that case you don't actually need an android application since you can use the built-in HFP client.

If you want to implement the server yourself using Java then you could look at this :
http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/07/27/bluetooth.html

You would also need to take a look at the Bluetooth Hands-Free Profile (HFP) protocol :
http://www.mcpc-jp.org/news/pdf/CCAP_Guideline_Ver10a.pdf